# Declining full-time offer during co-op

Tags: job-offer, resignation, co-op

I am currently in a co-op position at company A during my current school year. This co-op is scheduled to end in the Spring, and I have received an offer from company A for full-time permanent employment thereafter. This offer is currently pending.

I also applied for a full-time permanent position at company B. I received an offer from company B and have accepted it.

I now need to decline the offer from company A. However, I would still like to finish out my co-op position. How can I speak such that it's clear I'm still enthusiastic about my current project while also making it clear that I have already made a final decision in regards to moving to company B?

Comment: @Twyxz That's my current plan. I'm looking for additional input in case there is some specific wording that should be used.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I speak such that it's clear I'm still enthusiastic about my current project while also making it clear that I have already made a final decision in regards to moving to company B?

Just tell them as it is, truthfully. Say that you want to finish this Co-op but you have your eyes set elsewhere for the future.

Your other alternative is:

> I'll think about it

Then decline it when it comes to the time (if you want to avoid explaining, I don't recommend this but it's an option)

Comment: The only time I got burned in Co-op was by the City.  Basically did what they asked, extended when they asked, and when they told me to drop out of school, I said no.  The City of Houston then gave me F's for the Co-op work with them, and I talked to the Co-op department to have the classes assigned zero credit hours.  A strange road indeed, but honestly, one gets the experience and the money, and what more could you really ask for in a Co-op role?  My next Co-op, they offered me full time after graduation, and I've been happily employed ever since.

Answer (score 2):

> I now need to decline the offer from company A. However, I would still
>   like to finish out my co-op position. How can I speak such that it's
>   clear I'm still enthusiastic about my current project while also
>   making it clear that I have already made a final decision in regards
>   to moving to company B?

Just talk with them. Explain that you are enjoying your co-op role, but that you have accepted a full-time position elsewhere.

This is a normal occurrence and most managers of co-ops understand how this goes.

Being in a co-op program is about gaining experience and learning what you like and what you don't like. While Company A obviously likes you, they will understand that you have decided to go elsewhere. It's extremely unlikely that they won't let you continue your co-op term until its scheduled completion.

I hired co-ops in the past. I usually tried to hire the best ones. Sometimes they accepted, sometimes they didn't. I understood. I have remained friendly with one in particular and have always been a reference for him - even though he turned my job offer down. Frankly, he was smart to take a job elsewhere that was better than what I could offer.